# Notation for reflexive transitive closure in Coq

Tags: coq

Consider the reflexive transitive closure of a relation:

```
Inductive star {A : Type} (r : A -> A -> Prop) : A -> A -> Prop :=
| star_refl x : star r x x
| star_step x y z : r x y -> star r y z -> star r x z.
```

How can I give notation in Coq so that I can write `x ->* y`, perhaps adding a subscript to represent the relation `->__r`. This is certainly possible in Isabelle. Is there a clean way of doing it in Coq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use the notation system of Coq for this:

```
Notation "x '[' R ']*' y" := (star R x y) (at level 20).

Goal
  forall A (x y z : A) R,
    x [R]* y ->
    y [R]* z ->
    x [R]* z.
```

There are other notations that you can try, this an example explicitly mentioning the R.
You can only use this generic notation in combination with a special one for reduction.

```
Section Terms.

  Context (term : Type).
  Context (red : term -> term -> Prop).
  Notation "x → y" := (red x y) (at level 0).

  Notation "x →* y" := (x [red]* y) (at level 19).

  Goal forall x y, x → y -> x →* y.
  Abort.

End Terms.
```

Also note that you can do something fancy and use the notation already in the definition.

```
Reserved Notation "x '[' R ']*' y" (at level 20).

Inductive star {A : Type} (r : A -> A -> Prop) : A -> A -> Prop :=
| star_refl x : x [r]* x
| star_step x y z : r x y -> y [r]* z -> x [r]* z

where "x '[' R ']*' y" := (star R x y).
```

---

You can do a lot of things with notations. The following also works.

```
Notation "x '→<' R '>*' y" := (star R x y) (at level 20).

Goal
  forall A (x y z : A) R,
    x →<R>* y ->
    y →<R>* z ->
    x →<R>* z.
Abort.
```

Comment: the brackets are, unfortunately, necessary?

Comment: it seems a separation with the star is needed, as in x [r] * x. also it complains about the type A not being present in the last line

Comment: There is no need for separation, what I gave you compiles in Coq 8.11. Without the brackets, like `"x '→*' R y"` there is no separator between `R` and `y` so it can't differentiate from an application. I will update with another notation for you to see.